# css size and margins with percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I want to create a page that will always have the entire screen filled and nicely laid out. Using the following code works very well:

```
#posts{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#666;
}
.entry{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:20%;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}
```

There is one issue...It breaks on window resize. I am just curious as to why it does not work when the window resizes because due to the fact that the margins and sizes are done with percentages, they should change to the correct ones, right?

my questions is:

**Why does css percentages not work correctly when the viewer resizes the window, and what can I do that will make it resize correctly?**

remember to resize your window after load to actually see the issue I am speaking about.

## [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpbsn/9/)

EDIT1:

So clearly, based on the answers so far, this is an issue with what I want to do conflicting with masonry giving it's elements an absolute positioning. So the way this would be fixed is with some javascript/jquery line that can redo the margins on window resize according to the correct percentages...how can I do that?

Comment: If you comment out the Javascript it works fine (except for `#posts` disappearing because it has no dimension-affecting elements inside it due to its children all being `float`ed)

Comment: +1 to @winterblood. Everything works fine without the Javascript. There is nothing wrong with the CSS.

Comment: That Javascript is 100% necessary with my actual site. I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's because of the

`position: absolute;` property getting set by masonry.

> An element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus
>   takes up no space when placing other elements

If you remove that line, it works just fine, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/Zpbsn/3/embedded/result/)

Typically you wouldn't need masonry if all your elements are of equal width and height.

**UPDATE:**

Got a small script running, which will make this work with your current `html` implementation.

```
$(".entry").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    var currLeft = 0;
    var containerWidth = 0;
    var newLeft = 0;

    currLeft = parseInt($this[0].style.left, 10);
    containerWidth = parseInt($("#posts").width(), 10);

    newLeft = currLeft/containerWidth * 100;

    $this.css({
        "left": newLeft + "%"
    })
});
```

So, what the script does is take the `currLeft` in pixels and calculates the `newLeft` in percentage.

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/Zpbsn/13/embedded/result/)

Comment: they are not of all equal height...I set up a quick example and didn't bother with the specifics...masonry is necessary here. Is there some javascript that will make it work?

Comment: Ok, let me try something :)

Comment: does this really need to be run on every single div? will I need to throw this in the masonry recall?

Comment: Well, I suppose so. Better have this in a function and call it when needed. Fiddle is throwing some exception on masonry, so can't quite test it there.

Comment: That is annoying that there isn't some way to just reset it to the original css implementation and that I have to reset the left for each and every div, but I guess it's what you gotta do! I can make this a function and put it in a masonry callback. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so for some reason, when I make it into a function, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Zpbsn/15/

Comment: @RyanSaxe you'll have to call it after the initial masonry call as `left` is undefined until masonry is called. http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/Zpbsn/16/

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your `masonry plugin` check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpbsn/6/)

This `plugin` automatically applies `position` and `left top positions`

After removing the properties it will work fine.

**Updated**

Change you code like

**HTML**

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div class="entry-content"><div class="entry"></div></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#posts{
    width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    background:#666;
}
.entry-content{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:20%;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Zpbsn/10/

Comment: masonry is necessary here. Is there some javascript that will make it work?

Comment: Can you explain why this works, because it makes no sense to me why wrapping it would make a difference?...also, why the `clear:both` is necessary, because I have never seen that method before

Comment: Yes, you have used the `entry class` in `masonry plugin` and this plugin will apply `absolute position property to the entry div, it also sets left and top property`, so at the same time your `css` does not work. Thats why there is a need of an wrapper to your `entry div` which is `entry-content` and the css is **independent** to your `entry div` used in `masonry plugin`.

Comment: Alright, thank you!! But I still don't understand the purpose of `<div style="clear:both"></div>`...

Comment: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` is used for clearing, here we used `float:left property` in `entry-content` for these divs `clearing is necessary`. If you remove it then you will find that the `background` of `posts div` will not shown.